Issue with performing CRUD operations
My app is connected to node.js using an Android emulator device and the port on which the node backened was running on
final serverUrl = 'http://10.0.2.2:3000';

I have implemented CRUD in my app.
each time I try to update and delete an item in the app, the exception handled in the code is thrown. Furthermore, the item does not get deleted nor updated.
Future<List<Item>> fetchItems() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('$serverUrl/api/v1/items'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List<dynamic> itemList = jsonDecode(response.body);
      final List<Item> items =
          itemList.map((json) => Item.fromJson(json)).toList();
      return items;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to fetch items');
    }
  }

  Future<Item> addItem(String name) async {
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse('$serverUrl/api/v1/items'),
        headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
        body: jsonEncode({'name': name}));
   if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final dynamic json = jsonDecode(response.body);
    final Item item = Item.fromJson(json);
    return item;
   }else{
    throw Exception('Failed to fetch item');
   }
  }

  Future<void> updateItem(int id, String name) async {
    final response = await http.delete(
      Uri.parse('$serverUrl/api/v1/items/$id'),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: jsonEncode({"name": name}),
    );
    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      throw Exception('Failed to update item');
    }
  }

  Future<void> deleteItem(int id) async {
    final response = await http.delete(Uri.parse('$serverUrl/api/v1/items/$id'));
    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      throw Exception('Failed to delete item');
    }
  }

code to trigging update and delete
IconButton(
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                            onPressed: () {
                              dialog('Edit item', 'Edit', onPressed: () {
                                updateItem(item.id, nameController.text);
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                              });
                            },
                          ),



floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          dialog('Add item', 'Item name', onPressed: () {
            addItem(nameController.text);
            Navigator.pop(context);
          });
        },
        tooltip: 'Add button',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      )

 

below is the backend code for update and delete
const express = require('express');
  const app = express();
  const port = process.env.port || 3000;

onst itemList = [
    {id: 1, name: 'name here'},
];

app.put('/api/v1/items/:id', (req, res) => {
  let itemId = req.params.id;
  let updatedItem = {
    id: itemId,
    name: req.body.name
  }
  const index = itemList.findIndex(item => item.id === itemId);
  if(index !== -1){
    itemList[index] = updatedItem
    res.json(updatedItem);
  }else{
    res.status(404).json({message: 'Item not found'})
  }


})
app.delete('/api/v1/items/:id', (req, res) => {
    let itemId = req.params.id;
    let index = itemList.findIndex(item => item.id === itemId);
    if(index!== -1){
     let deletedItem = itemList.splice(index, 1);
      res.json(deletedItem[0])
    }else{
      res.status(404).json({message: 'Item not found'})
    }
 
})


The only thing wrong I can see at first glance is that you use http.delete in your updateItem function, I guess that's why updates don't work (but it should still delete the item).
Where is the error occurring? Does the app actually reach the server (add some console.logs or break points to check this), does the server get the right parameter and perform the right operation? Does it return the expected status code? Then back in your Flutter app, can you see this same code (once again, use break points or print statements)?
I hope this helps you to track down the issue, and make the problem a lot less broad.
